# OpenglES EGL_BAD_MATCH error

Tags: android, opengl-es

I have this config :

```
int[] attribList = {
                EGL14.EGL_RED_SIZE, 8,
                EGL14.EGL_GREEN_SIZE, 8,
                EGL14.EGL_BLUE_SIZE, 8,
                EGL14.EGL_ALPHA_SIZE, 8,
                //EGL14.EGL_DEPTH_SIZE, 16,
                //EGL14.EGL_STENCIL_SIZE, 8,
                EGL14.EGL_RENDERABLE_TYPE,EGL14.EGL_OPENGL_ES2_BIT,
                EGL14.EGL_NONE, 0,      // placeholder for recordable [@-3]
                EGL14.EGL_NONE
        };
```

And when i call eglCreatePbufferSurface() with this config it raise me the erro : EGL_BAD_MATCH/

Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you have set `EGL_PBUFFER_BIT` for the `EGL_SURFACE_TYPE` in the attributes passed into `eglChooseConfig()` call.